# Wordpress ACF get_field returning empty data/null though field is filled

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

A little new to ACF and I've looked through the related stack overflow questions and yet can not seem to piece together this.

I am attempting to render a link using custom fields in WordPress and the `get_field()` function, yet I keep returning `"empty data"` and `"null"` for my results. I understand `get_field()` will return 2 results, but I can't seem to extract my desired links. Any help is appreciated.

Custom fields:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnWQo.png)

This is my code base:

```
    $trend_one = get_field('trend_one');
    $trend_two = get_field('trend_two');
    $trend_three = get_field('trend_three');


?>
<div class='trend_bar'>
    <div class="trend_item">TRENDING:</div>
    <div class='trend_item'><?php console_log($trend_one); ?></div>
    <div class='trend_item'><?php console_log($trend_two); ?></div>
    <div class='trend_item'><?php console_log($trend_three); ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log` is a javascript function.   Not sure where you picked up `console_log` - but if it's a function you've written / added, you need to share that code.  There's no need, really, though -  In PHP, you'd use `var_dump($trend_one)` (or `var_export`).  Note you may get recommendations to use `echo` or `print_r`, but those are limited - echo won't work for objects / arrays, and print_r will _only_ work for objects / arrays, whereas `var_dump` or `var_export` will handle _any_ variable contents.

Comment: Please read how to create an [mcve] - while your code is part of the equation, there's much more to the story, and if we don't know where you've put this code _specifically_, that could be the problem.  `get_field` will only work in the right context (when the WP `post` has been set up), so knowing where in your template, which template, etc. matters.

Comment: There are cases when the field name won’t work - in these cases you have to use field ID (that’s a long, unique code for the field, the ACF documentation tells you how to get it). And the other thing: try to set the second parameter of the get_field() function - that’s the post ID of the WP object whose ACF field you’re trying to get.

Comment: For those of you wondering why I have console_log in a php script, it was something our senior dev developed as way to view stuff in the console. I've put put the code below in a lower answer but I would appreciate it if you wouldn't down vote this just cause it has something you've never seen or thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using console.log inside PHP?

It should be:

```
<?php echo $trend_one['url']; ?>
<?php echo $trend_two; ?>
<?php echo $trend_three; ?>
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help! Note that echo won't handle some variable types (arrays, objects, booleans) - may I suggest that you propose `var_dump` or `var_export` instead?

Comment: @cale_b Hi, thanks. I wasn't sure if the OP is asking about the correct way to output the value, or the correct way to debug. Since console.log is not PHP, I thought the answer might be as simple as using `echo`. Shouldn't we get a PHP error, if we use console.log? - which is why I was a bit confused, how the code returns "null" or "empty data".

Comment: Agreed on all points.  My only point is that `echo array(1,2,3);` will display the word `Array` on the screen, and you might want to suggest `var_dump` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's that code you wanted for the console_log in PHP

```
function console_log( $data ) {
if ( empty( $data ) ){
    print '<script>console.log("Empty Data");</script>';
    print '<script>console.log(' . json_encode( $data ) . ');</script>';
} else {
    if ( is_array( $data ) || is_object( $data ) ){
        print '<script>console.table(' . json_encode( $data ) . ');</script>';
        print '<script>console.log(' . json_encode( $data ) . ');</script>';

    } else {
        print '<script>console.log(' . json_encode( $data ) . ');</script>';
    }
}
```

}